# Using SUDO with NVM?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

How is it to execute something like `sudo npm rebuild` or `sudo node` if  Node.js was installed by NVM ?

Each time I type `sudo` command, my console tries to execute `npm` or `node` program in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/lib`, neither of which do exist.[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If `npm` nor `node` exists using `sudo` will not make them work.

Comment: i tried to rebuild a plugin that is based on `node-gyp`. But `npm rebuild` only works with sudo.

I'm using Linux Mint here, I had node installed via `apt-get` before. But since I migrated to NVM and download latest node package, I uninstalled my old node, now `sudo npm rebuild` doesn't work. I just need my `npm` to work with `sudo`

Comment: It's not a good idea to run node and NVM commands with `sudo` privilege.
It's not recommended from Node.js and NVM developers too...

Comment: tried to add symlinks in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib` ?

Comment: @yergo: how to do that? I'm try to add new node (NVM version) to my $PATH with no success

Comment: @RikyTres: I know but somehow one of my node modules needs sudo privileges. especially modules with `node-gyp` dependencies like `lwip` or `node-printer`

Answer (score 0):

Try creating symlinks in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/lib`. Not a strong solution, but may be enough.

```
sudo ln -s /home/denny/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
```

`sudo` for writing in system location. Suggestions [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/43) may happen useful, especially [rvmsudo](http://rvm.io/integration/sudo) or [group access](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/43#issuecomment-30602561).

## Other suggestion:

According to comment, you may try to create a bash script at `/home/denny/npm.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
PTH="/home/denny/.nvm/versions/node/$(node -v)/bin/npm"
$PTH
```

chmode it `+x` properly and create symlink with this:

```
sudo ln -s /home/denny/npm.sh /usr/bin/npm
```

Should always check for `node -v` and run `npm` from proper directory.

Comment: After searching for a whole day, this solution is the best I know. The only problem is : I need to create another symlinks for node & npm:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs/home/denny/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.0/bin/node`

and do that every time I change node version using NVM.

Comment: @denny have improved my answer, you may may be interested in testing it :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this to run the Atom installation script, but I didn't want to permanently change my machine setup. So, I did:

```
sudo bash
```

and then I sourced the nvm.sh file in my user's home directory tree:

```
source /home/ada-lovelace/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

That let me run the necessary commands with root. Of course, this means the very next time I need to run node in a session with root I'll have to do these steps again, but I don't anticipate needing to do this in the near future.